# Use glPrimitiveRestartIndex to draw GL_LINE_LOOPS

Tags: opengl, primitive

I have some questions about glPrimitiveRestartIndex and how to use it. Basically, I want to draw a number of contours with GL_LINE_LOOP, whose vertices are stored in an array.
I've read the chapter in the OpenGL Super Bible about using glPrimitiveRestart, but it's not really clear to me.
From what I understood, you can only use this function with glDrawElements, and not with glDrawArrays by storing a "spectial vertex" inside the array...is that correct?
Also, how is it possible to use glPrimitiveRestart if the contours / line loops have different amounts of vertices...let's say one loop is in the z=100-plane, which has 40 vertices, and another one is in the z=99-plane, which has only 16 vertices. 
How could I set the glPrimitiveRestartIndex, so that the different loops are rendered correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the restart index to one of your existing vertex indices, you pick a value you aren't using as an index, and insert that between primitives.

Obviously if you're not drawing with indices, it won't work.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood it then.